# Magento custom theme pulling in images but not styles or scripts

Tags: magento, content-management-system, e-commerce, skin

I have a magento store where I am trying to develop a custom theme. I copied the files from skin/frontend/default/default and app/design/frontend/default/default to skin/frontend/occasions/occasions and app/design/frontend/occasions/occasions respectively, then went to system->configuration->design and changed all the package and theme text boxes to occasions, but when I load my site, it pulls in the images from occasions/occasions but not the css or js, which it is pulling in from base/default.

Any ideas? Here is a code sample from the head tag to illustrate my issue:

```
<link rel="icon" href="xxxxx/skin/frontend/occasions/occasions/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="xxxxx/skin/frontend/occasions/occasions/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="xxxxx/skin/frontend/base/default/css/styles.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="xxxxx/skin/frontend/base/default/css/widgets.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="xxxxx/skin/frontend/base/default/css/print.css" media="print" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="xxxxx/js/lib/ds-sleight.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="xxxxx/skin/frontend/base/default/js/ie6.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that when I used the filemanager on site5 to copy the files across, it removed the css files from the css folder and moved them up a level, to skin/frontend/occasions/occasions/. When I recreated the css folder and moved the css files. this resolved the problem.